# How do i finger the second measure?

Tags: piano

So this piece of music is for the piano with a treble clef and bass clef. The second measure of this chunk of music has a grace note c that leads to a F/D in the right hand (treble clef). however, when I play the rest it sounds chunky and the F comes in way too loud when its up to speed. At the moment I play all the F notes in that second measure all the way through with my right thumb. should I instead play it with my left thumb? its a little more awkward and involved  but its quieter and I don't know if its the right call. is there anyway to play those grace notes and move into a multi note chord that wont sound to harsh?[image]

Thanks

Comment: if needed the rhythm for this is different. two 16th notes equal one 8th and a 16th. its a long short long flow.

Comment: Stick with the Fs played by r.h. thumb, but rotate the hand/wrist clockwise, to take some weight off that thumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play the F's with your right hand thumb.

Using your left thumb is trying to work round your real problem, which is that you need to practice playing two notes with one hand, but at different dynamic levels.

Slow down the tempo till you can play the D louder and the F softer. I would finger the Bb C D and top F's with 2 3 4 5 in both bars.

You could start by practising an exercise like Bb F C F D F F' F, fingered 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1, making the 2 3 4 5 loud and the 1's soft. Then do the same thing but with two-note "chords".